# Android Mediaplayer Servicio

Tags: java, android

Tengo un servicio que se ejecuta  con mediaplayer la cosa es que al cerrarlo deja de reproducir la cancion y el servicio se reinicia, quiero mantener la cancion reproducion normalmente aunque se cierre la aplicacion ya que es un servicio

```
    public class ForegroundService extends Service{

    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        player=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.chu);

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();



        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(player!=null){
            player.pause();
            player.release();
        }

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto a lo que comentas:

> al cerrarlo deja de reproducir la cancion y el servicio se reinicia

Esto es porque estas definiendo  `Service.START_STICKY` , al cerrar la aplicación el servicio es recreado y vuelve a reproducir desde 0 :

> **[Service.START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY)** : recrea el servicio si la aplicación se
>   destruye.:

**No existe una propiedad para continuar la reproducción del MediaPlayer cuando la aplicación se destruye. Pero puedes realizar esto guardando la posición de reproducción y cuando se reinicie el servicio, si es que existe una posición guardada mayor que 0 (posición inicial), entonces continua la reproducción.**

```
public class Preferences {

    private static final String PREFS = "SoundPreferences";

    public static void setMediaPosition(Context ctx, int position) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().putInt("position", position).apply();
    }

    public static int getMediaPosition(Context ctx) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getInt("position", 0);
    }

}
```

Primeramente configura tu servicio en dentro del archivo AndroidManifest.xml , es importante agregar la propiedad `android:stopWithTask="false"`:

esto para que cuando se realice la destrucción de la aplicación llame el método `onTaskRemoved()`, donde se guardara la última posición de reproducción :

```
@Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onTaskRemoved(), save current position: " + player.getCurrentPosition());
        //instead of stop service, save the current position.
        //stopSelf();
        Preferences.setMediaPosition(getApplicationContext(), player.getCurrentPosition());
    }
```

Al iniciar el servicio (ya que tienes configurado [Service.START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY), se reproducirá desde la posición guardada.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand()");
    if(Preferences.getMediaPosition(getApplicationContext())>0){
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand(), position stored, continue from position : " + Preferences.getMediaPosition(getApplicationContext()));
        player.start();
        player.seekTo(Preferences.getMediaPosition(getApplicationContext()));
    }else {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand() Start!...");
        player.start();
    }
    //re-create the service if it is killed.
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

---

Este es un código de ejemplo de un servicio que realiza lo anteriormente descrito:

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "BackgroundSoundService";
    MediaPlayer player;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind()" );
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jorgesys_song);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand()");
        if(Preferences.getMediaPosition(getApplicationContext())>0){
            Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand(), position stored, continue from position : " + Preferences.getMediaPosition(getApplicationContext()));
            player.start();
            player.seekTo(Preferences.getMediaPosition(getApplicationContext()));
        }else {
            Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand() Start!...");
            player.start();
        }
        //re-create the service if it is killed.
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onUnBind()");
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop()");
        Preferences.setMediaPosition(getApplicationContext(), player.getCurrentPosition());
    }

    public void onPause() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy() , service stopped! Media position: " + player.getCurrentPosition());
        //Save current position before destruction.
        Preferences.setMediaPosition(getApplicationContext(), player.getCurrentPosition());
        player.pause();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
        Preferences.setMediaPosition(getApplicationContext(), player.getCurrentPosition());
    }

    //Inside AndroidManifest.xml add android:stopWithTask="false" to the Service definition.
    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onTaskRemoved(), save current position: " + player.getCurrentPosition());
        //instead of stop service, save the current position.
        //stopSelf();
        Preferences.setMediaPosition(getApplicationContext(), player.getCurrentPosition());
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, no pude contestar antes por que estaba en examenes de la U, gracias a tu respuesta puedo entender mejor los servicios, pero aun me queda la duda, como haran los reproductores comunes de android en seguir reproduciendo una cancion aun cuando son cerrados sin ninguna interrupcion