# Proceso en funcionamiento con aplicación destruida

Tags: android, android-studio, servidor, proceso

Existe alguna forma para hacer que un proceso siga corriendo aunque el usuario haya destruido la aplicación o es necesario de un servidor que haga el proceso y este informe a la aplicación? Como si fuera segundo plano pero sin que la aplicación aparezca en lo de aplicaciones abiertas.

La idea de este proceso es que esté en funcionamiento bastante tiempo.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes realizar un servicio y tomar en cuenta [los limites de ejecución en segundo plano](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html?hl=es) ya que han cambiado para las aplicaciones con sistema operativo Android Oreo 8.0 (API 26) o posterior.

Lo que debes realizar es un servicio que tenga definido [START_STICKY](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110062/se-me-reinicia-un-servicio-despues-de-cerrar-el-app/110163#110163) para que recree tu servicio aunque la aplicación sea cerrada.

```
  @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
          ...
          //Proceso a realizar.
          ...
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }
```

No olvidar declarar el servicio en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
 <service android:name=".MyService" />
```

Revisa el ejemplo en el cual aunque la app se encuentre en segundo plano continua actualizando la Geolocalizacion:

[onLocationChanged() no funciona en las ultimas versiones de android en modo screen off](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/294386/onlocationchanged-no-funciona-en-las-ultimas-versiones-de-android-en-modo-scre/294449#294449)

Otro ejemplo en el cual se continua reproduciendo un audio:

[Android Mediaplayer Servicio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101603/android-mediaplayer-servicio)

otros:

[Servicio no funciona en android 7+](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146627/servicio-no-funciona-en-android-7)

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría le dieras una leída completa a la documentación de Android relativa a [Servicios](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=es-419) ya que esto te ayudara mucho a darte una idea de como estructurar y armar uno. En especial con lo que trabajaras sera con la bandera **START_STICKY**.

Con un **Service** podrás tener tareas ejecutándose en segundo plano aunque la app principal ya no este en el foco del usuario.

**Ojo** A partir de Android Lollipop, aunque establezcas un Service con todo lo necesario para que siga funcionando en segundo plano aunque la app haya sido destruida, el mismo SO Android sólo deja en funcionamiento permanente aquellos Service que esten asociados a una App de sistema, y el mismo SO determinara, para optimizar batería, memoria, etc., que Services siguen en marcha (App de sistema) y cuales no (apps de terceros).